# Gaining experience in salesforce

Tags: administration

Are there any other projects like "Recruiting app" in salesforce that we can build for practicing admin and developer concepts to gain hands on experience?

Comment: Have you heard of Trailhead? [Click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/en)

Comment: developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

Comment: Ya I have done almost all the project available in Trailhead, currently working on my last project. As I don't have job as a developer, I would like to gain as much as hands on experience over these concepts. Are there any other project other than trailhead that could help achieve this?  Thanks In advance.

Comment: https://github.com/choppen5/TwilioSalesforceClick2Dial -- Install this package in your developer org and play with it. I have been working on this from last two days and learnt lot of new things.

Comment: thanks for  the info Javanoob. There seems to be a lot of info regarding this.

Answer (score 5):

### Hands On

As many others mentioned, [trailhead](https://developer.saleforce.com/trailhead) is a great way to learn. Other than that, I would suggest taking a look at the [workbooks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/?filter_text=Workbook&service=All%20Services&select_type=&version=36.0&lang=en-us&sort=title). These workbooks are great step by step guides which walk you through different areas of Salesforce, and personally I found as valuable tools for learning what specifically is needed to pass your certification exams. There are also [courses](http://www.salesforce.com/services-training/training_certification/training.jsp) to help you get ready for these exams.

### DIY

Depending on if you are a hands-on type learner, I would suggest getting your own [dev org](https://developer.salesforce.com/signup), thinking of your own app to build, then build it out on your own. This is great experience as you are defining your own requirements, then building it out and testing it. It's a challenge as it might be hard to identify something to build on your own, but this would be a very close 'real world' scenario. Maybe try an event management application.

### Communities

If you want a less hand-on approach, you can always be active in the communities, [SFSE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com), [developer forum](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums), and [success community](https://success.salesforce.com/). Being active doesn't always mean answering questions - maybe just look through posts and learn what the question is asking and understanding the answer. This gives insight to other peoples issues which you may encounter some day and helps you understand parts of Salesforce that trailhead and other sources don't always let you dive into.
There are also [local meetup](http://www.meetup.com/pro/salesforcedevs/) communities for your to engage and discuss Salesforce. These groups are often run by MVPs or highly engaged Salesforce users. This would get you access to many other users that eat, sleep, and breathe Salesforce as well.

Comment: Thnak you Zainogj. I would start my work on the workbooks. They seem to provide good learnng experience.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to learn Salesforce is [Trailhead - click here](http://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead)

developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

visit , Signup

First go with "Beginner" modules/trails.

Comment: Ya I have done almost all the project available in Trailhead, currently working on my last project. As I don't have job as a developer, I would like to gain as much as hands on experience over these concepts. Are there any other project other than trailhead that could help me achieve this? Thanks In advance.

Comment: For practice purpose - you can go and visit AppExchange - See different apps there - Watch Screenshots carefully - you could install 'Free' of them -- and try to implement functionalities like them. That will be great !  (If you get Unmanaged Package -Apps' there -dont look into the code initially --- Just use your way of implementing things---Then see into their codes and improvise)